# Change repository local folder to sync from

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

How can I change it so that GitHub syncs my repository from another folder?

For example, my repository is located at (F:GameBackUp\GameName) and now I want it to check my original folder (D:GameProjects\GameName) and sync all changed files.

I want what it does right now when I submit a change, only I don't want the .git folder to be in the same directory as my project.

Comment: Why not `git push` from `F:...` and then `git pull` from `D:...`?

Comment: You can also just copy the repository from `F:` to `D:`. The syncing with Github will just work

Comment: jep been copying it ever sine, just wanted to find a way to make it easier and also be able to maybe later share the project with other people.

Answer (score 0):

So since you have two local forks, what you could do is push the branch from one to github, `git push origin branch-name`, and then in your other local fork, fetch your origin from Github, `git fetch origin`, then you can you can merge the branch from the other fork, `git merge origin/branch-name`, you can check that both forks are hooked up to your origin by running git remote -v in both

Answer (score 0):

> so basically what it does right now when you submit a change just that I don't want the .git folder to be in the same directory as my project.

You can move the `.git` folder to a different location. But there is a drawback: You have to specify `--git-dir` on every `git` call, because git is expecting it where it currently is.

See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git

Another solution is to add a subdirectory to the repository root folder.